# debian installation cannot detect partition

Tags: debian, partition, usb, system-installation

In partition phase of installing debian, I have this sdb partition:

```
$lsblk
...
sdb      8:16   1  14.4G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1   3.7G  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   1   2.8M  0 part 
└─sdb3   8:19   1  10.5G  0 part
```

now partition `sdb1` and `sdb2` were made from `sudo dd bs=4M if=debian-10.0.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso of=/dev/sdb`, and the partition `sdb3` was made from `fdisk`. But when used in debian installed, then it shows only the whole device, not particular partitions. In "partition disks" phase, only the device is shown:

```
SCSI1 (0,0,0)(sda) - 15.5 GB Kingston DataTraveler 3.0
```

Which is just the device, but I cannot see particular partition, which of course I want to use (`sdb3`). How can I?

Continue here:
[How to partition usb to become bootable for debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597925/how-to-partition-usb-to-become-bootable-for-debian)

Comment: If you're in the process of partition disks, then it's proper for the installer to only show you devices, since the expectation is that the disk is not partitioned or doesn't have the partitions you need. Have you tried the option that allows you to choose from existing partitions?

Comment: In your text and in the `lsblk` output it is `sdb` but in the Debian installer output it is `sda`. Typo from copying manually?

Comment: When you write an ISO to a whole disk you both destroy all other partition definitions and only allow the partitions (and size) given in the ISO. You need a completely different approach to partitioning if you also want the ISO image contents (not the original ISO, that is not possible) in some partition.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa there is not such option - I have choose to partition manualy which showed me only the device as you said. But i have no idea how to open "choose from exitsin partition"

Comment: @Isaac, I do not get it. It is true I have 2 partitions of iso, but that does not mean I could not make my own and use that one for root.I should not need 2 devices, one with bootable files (iso) and another for root, when I have enought room in the first device to partition it and used it for both purposes

Comment: When you do `dd of=/dev/sdb` you are writing to the whole disk, not a partition. That destroys any other partition table, and, depending on the specific ISO involved, the installation of isolinux as well. You need to find a way to write to a partition **/dev/sdbX** where X is a number, not `/dev/sdb`.

Comment: @Isaac, so even thought I have enought room *after* writing the whole device, the debian installator does not see other partition made due to the table that has been destroyed?

Comment: @Herdsman I fail to remember the exact way in which the internals of a debian ISO is built. But I am sure that if you partition a disk (or an USB pen drive), copy the correct files to each of the partitions (extract the contents of the ISO) and then carry on creating as many partitions as you see fit, everything will work just fine.

Comment: @Isaac you say I have to extract all ISO content. But I don't know how to instruct `dd` command to split its copying into 2 partition. As from the post, you can see when I tried to `dd` the ISO file, it *automatically* made 2 partition (`sdb1`,`sdb2`), without having to do it manually via `fdisk`. But if I want to `dd` into my partition, will it made a "sub-partition" inside the specified one? Or why does `dd` ISO files made 2 partition with UEFI content?

Comment: @Herdsman You may follow the procedure [here](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/amd64/ch04s03.html.en) (directly from debian) starting at point **4.3.3**

Comment: @Isaac in adding installer section, they are using files I do not have. Specifically, they use `vmlinux` and `initrd.gz`. I have only ISO file which is 4GB long. So I do not know, if I should mount it and copy non-existing files.

Comment: Ok, maybe you shuld try this other method: https://www.howtogeek.com/196933/how-to-boot-linux-iso-images-directly-from-your-hard-drive/

Comment: Or, maybe, follow the advice here: https://github.com/thias/glim

Comment: Or, this is a good guide: https://www.pcsuggest.com/create-a-multiboot-usb-drive-with-grub-in-linux/

Comment: @Isaac so I cannot simply `dd` the iso file to `sdb1` partition? I have asked here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597925/how-to-partition-usb-to-become-bootable-for-debian