# How to partition usb to become bootable for debian?

Tags: debian, partition, system-installation, partition-table

**[split from here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597865/debian-installation-cannot-detect-partition?noredirect=1#comment1116105_597865)**

I have install ISO file `firmware-10.4.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso`, 4GB long. I would like to make my usb drive partition ("say `sdb1`) to be bootable. I have followed the official debian documentation: https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/amd64/ch04s03.html.en. But they say I can have partition of length 1GB, but that is not sufficient for the ISO file. What I have done so far (assuming my usb is `/dev/sdb`):

1. `# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb` #zeroed the whole device including the partition table MBR
2. `# fdidk /dev/sdb` #made new partition /dev/sdb1, 4GB long with bootable flag on
3. `# install-mbr /dev/sdb` #make new partition table on the device

Now, I should continue with the manual to make filesystem `mkdosfs /dev/sdb1`, `syslinux /dev/sdb1`, mount that partition and copy 2 files: `vmlinuz` and `initrd.gz` which I do not have (I have only ISO file downloaded from debian.org). So instead, I have made this to boot the partition:

4. `# dd bs=4 if=firmware-10.4.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso of=/dev/sdb1 status=progress && sync` #copy the ISO file to that partition

If I try to boot from the usb, will I be able to make new partition in partition phase for root directory on the *same* usb?

Comment: How big is your pen-drive?

Comment: 15.5GB. But I am not sure If I want to use Live ISO. Now I have installed the "normal" version (see the file)

Comment: A bootable ISO is an ISO, any ISO should work.

Comment: Now, to topic, If I make (or made) partition table to zero-ed drive, partition it for 4GB and then `dd` there the iso, will I be able to boot from that partition (and then make new partition for root dir in installation?)

Comment: (1) You only need to zero the first megabyte of the disk, nothing more. Zeroing more is just wasting the live of you pendrive (assuming it is a flash drive). (2) if you zero and partition you have an usable pendrive. If you dd to /dev/sdb, you DESTROY the partitioning already done, and a new one appears (the one inside the ISO). (3) Yes, the pendrive should boot, but no information of the partitions you did would be available (because you overwrite them, and them are destroyed).

Comment: @Isaac, asked here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597937/grub-install-error-cannot-find-efi-directory-for-live-usb

Comment: A hybrid DVD for both flash drives & DVD drives does not use a standard partition table. And dd overwrites everything at the size of whatever you are copying. You want a persistent type install or if flash drive large enough you can do a full install. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

Comment: @oldfred so my intent to use the same drive to boot as well as to make there a partition for root dir (user data) is called hybrid CD? And is only possible to live installation? (not full firmware - iso file, e.g. `firmware-10.4.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso`)? I am following this tutorial to make grub-loader manually: https://www.pcsuggest.com/create-a-multiboot-usb-drive-with-grub-in-linux/, will it work?

Comment: @oldfred can you please look here -> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597993/how-to-make-grub-cfg-file-for-debian-installation , there I am trying to make a bootloader for that hybrid cd

Comment: Yes, but then you cannot use dd to copy ISO as that is a hybrid DVD/flashdrive configuration with no partition table. And dd erases everything permanently. I have always created my own multiple boot using grub in similar fashion, both old BIOS & now new UEFI. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot
Examples - you may copy & edit for your path & ISO version
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples & 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1549847

Comment: @oldfred but can I actually install standard debian iso, and not live? (even thought I can make it persistent). For example live does not have root, and I think there will be more disadvantages, so I would like to make hybrid but still have full version of kernel. Is that possible?

Comment: Choices are live, live with persistence & full install (from another live installer). With dd you only get the live version. I prefer to boot ISO with grub as then I can have more than one install on a flash drive and usually now with larger flash drives or an external SSD have full install & multiple repair ISO on that drive. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083330/how-to-make-an-usb-ubuntu-installation-more-compatible-with-different-computers/1083812#1083812 Pros & cons 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step