# grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory -- for live usb

Tags: grub, uefi, boot-loader, live-usb

I am trying to make my usb pen drive bootable according to this:
https://www.pcsuggest.com/create-a-multiboot-usb-drive-with-grub-in-linux/, what I have done:

`# fdisk /dev/sdb`  #made new partition /dev/sdb1 4GB

`# mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdb1`  #vfat filesytem

`# mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt; cd /mnt; mkdir boot boot_iso` #mount, make 2 dirs

`# grub-install /dev/sdb --target=x86_64-efi --boot-directory=boot/ --force-extra-removable --force` #install GRUB

which triggered error:

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
```

What should I do? I do not have any EFI directory, I want to create one

Comment: If you do want an EFI partition then use Gparted (or similar) and ask it to create an EFI partition (quite small, I believe is 100 MByte or so) usually at the start of the disk.

Comment: so I need to make another partition and then 100M and then used it with `grub-install /dev/sdb2 --target=x86_64-efi-signed`?

Comment: @Isaac or how to do that?

Comment: Read here (use sgdisk): https://fedoramagazine.org/managing-partitions-with-sgdisk/

Comment: But, As I already said, gparted should be easier: https://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: Did you mount the ESP? I have used this for flash drive on sdb. `sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /mnt -o uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022` then the install command. `sudo grub-install --removable --boot-directory=/mnt/boot --efi-directory=/mnt/EFI/BOOT /dev/sdb`